# Horizontal Indeterminate Progress Bar in Android

Tags: android, progress-bar

I need to create a horizontal progress bar in my Android app. It works fine on one phone and does not work properly on the other phone.

[image]

On Samsung phones, it works as expected, but on Nexus phones, the progress bar is very stretched and does not look like a progress bar.

[image]

I am not sure whet is the issue.

My xml looks like below:

```
<ProgressBar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:id="@+id/background_progress_indicator"
    android:layout_weight="0.2"
    style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
    android:indeterminate="true"
    android:indeterminateDrawable="@anim/progressbar_sync"
    />
```

progressbar_sync:

```
<animation-list
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:oneshot="false">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/indeterminate1" android:duration="200" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/indeterminate2" android:duration="200" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/indeterminate3" android:duration="200" />
</animation-list>
```

Comment: Could you please provide `@anim/progressbar_sync` content

Comment: Updated in the question

Comment: I have a feeling that it is related to `layout_weight`, but just throwing a guess since I'm on the go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both phones use the progressbar widget style from the internal android library.
My guess would be that the style is different for each android library since they are different brand phones

I would try using an external library
this is a good start
https://github.com/castorflex/SmoothProgressBar

Comment: Thanks I used it. Not same what i expected, but can be lived with. Thanks.